# Forcing text to be on top of figures

Tags: graphics

I am trying to put some text on top of the figure like

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}

  \subfloat{\label{figur:1}\includegraphics[width=79mm, ,height=200pt]{./pic1.eps}}

   \tiny{\put(-45,-5) {Discriminator}}
    \tiny{\put(175,-5) {Discriminator}}        
    \tiny{\put(-95,185) {Some test}}
    \tiny{  \put(130,180) {Some test again}}

    \subfloat{\label{figur:2}\includegraphics[width=79mm, ,height=200pt]{./pic2.eps}}  

\end{tabular}   
\caption{bla bla bla}
\label{MVA_syst_JES}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

the problem is that although the "Discriminators" appear at the right place, and the "Some test" on the left figure, the "Some test again" is below the right figure.. How can I force my text to be on top ?

[image]

Comment: yeah, that is what I thought, but still does not work...

Comment: note that `\tiny` does not take an argument so `
   \tiny{\put(-45,-5) {Discriminator}}` makes all following text tiny the `{}` group and the following `\tiny` isn't doing anything. To put the figures below the text simply put them before the text in the source.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\put(175,-5) {\tiny Discriminator}%
\subfloat{\label{figur:1}\includegraphics[width=79mm,height=200pt]{example-image-a}}
\put(-95,185) {\tiny Some test}
\put(185,-5) {\tiny Discriminator}
&        
\subfloat{\label{figur:2}\includegraphics[width=79mm,height=200pt]{example-image-b}}  
\put(-95,185) {\tiny Some test again}
\end{tabular}   
\caption{bla bla bla}
\label{MVA_syst_JES}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Some comments:

- It was not clear to me why you were using a `tabular` environment, so in my code I used it.
- I changed the `center` environment to `\centering` to avoid additional extra vertical spacing.
- `\tiny` (and the other font size switches) are declarations and do not take an argument; you should use them in the form `{\tiny text}` if grouping is required.
- The texts that will go over the images has to be `\put` after the images have been included.